# Oracle SQL CASE Including the expression clause Error ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a `CASE` statement that works fine, and i want to include it in another `CASE` statement but i am getting a `ORA-00936: missing expression` error as i want it to use `IN` not `=`.

Following this logic.

> The CASE statement can be used in Oracle/PLSQL.
>   You could use the CASE statement in a SQL statement as follows: (includes the expression clause)

```
CASE owner
  WHEN 'SYS' THEN 'The owner is SYS'
  WHEN 'SYSTEM' THEN 'The owner is SYSTEM'
  ELSE 'The owner is another value'
END
```

**MY Code:**

```
CASE (CASE WHEN l.dnames = 'II-SH' THEN 'IW' 
     WHEN l.dnames = 'IIC-SH' THEN 'IW' 
     WHEN l.dnames = 'CD' THEN 'RPFX' 
     WHEN l.dnames LIKE '%-%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, '-',2,1)+1, 20 )
     WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EXCR%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames,  (INSTR(l.dnames, 'EXCR',1,1)+4),20)
     WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' AND l.ditems LIKE '%/%' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(l.ditems, 1,INSTR(l.ditems, '/',1)-1),'SINV')
     WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(l.ditems,'SINV'),'INV'), '[0-9]','')
     WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EX%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, 'EX',1)+2 ,20)
     ELSE NULL 
     END)
WHEN IN ('BA', 'BG', 'BT') THEN 'First'
WHEN IN ('BW', 'PF', 'SS') THEN 'Second'
WHEN IN ('TC', 'NE') THEN 'Third'
ELSE NULL
END AS DGROUP
```

Comment: is this your full code? i don't see where the "l" alias is defined

Comment: ISO SQL 2011, Feature F262, “Extended CASE expression”.  Apparently not supported by Oracle.

Comment: @jarlh yeh its a shame as it would tidy this right up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clever, but that is not how `case` or `in` works.  You can do:

```
SELECT (CASE (CASE WHEN l.dnames = 'II-SH' THEN 'IW' 
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'IIC-SH' THEN 'IW' 
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'CD' THEN 'RPFX' 
                   WHEN l.dnames LIKE '%-%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, '-',2,1)+1, 20 )
                   WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EXCR%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames,  (INSTR(l.dnames, 'EXCR',1,1)+4),20)
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' AND l.ditems LIKE '%/%' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(l.ditems, 1,INSTR(l.ditems, '/',1)-1),'SINV')
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(l.ditems,'SINV'),'INV'), '[0-9]','')
                   WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EX%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, 'EX',1)+2 ,20)
              END)
            WHEN 'BA' THEN 'FIRST'
            WHEN 'BG' THEN 'FIRST'
            WHEN 'BT' THEN 'First'
            WHEN 'BW' THEN 'Second'
            WHEN 'PF' THEN 'Second'
            WHEN 'SS' THEN 'Second'
            WHEN 'TC' THEN 'Third'
            WHEN 'NE' THEN 'Third'
        END) AS DGROUP
```

However, that is rather hard to read.  I would encourage you to use subqueries:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN FieldName IN ('BA', 'BG', 'BT') THEN 'First'
             WHEN FieldName IN ('BW', 'PF', 'SS') THEN 'Second'
             WHEN FieldName IN ('TC', 'NE') THEN 'Third'
        END) AS DGROUP
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN l.dnames = 'II-SH' THEN 'IW' 
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'IIC-SH' THEN 'IW' 
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'CD' THEN 'RPFX' 
                   WHEN l.dnames LIKE '%-%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, '-',2,1)+1, 20 )
                   WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EXCR%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames,  (INSTR(l.dnames, 'EXCR',1,1)+4),20)
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' AND l.ditems LIKE '%/%' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(l.ditems, 1,INSTR(l.ditems, '/',1)-1),'SINV')
                   WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(l.ditems,'SINV'),'INV'), '[0-9]','')
                   WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EX%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, 'EX',1)+2 ,20)
              END) as FieldName
```

I should also note that the list of values in the outer `case` doesn't match the list produced by the `inner` cause.

Comment: So it is not possible to use `IN` in this way in a CASE statement? Each value will have to defined?

Comment: @Matt . . . You can use `IN`.  You just need an argument to the left of the `IN`.

Comment: Yes, but if the argument is large (like the sub case statement) it looks more tidy the way you did it ..... as always .... because your a genious.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of CASE, "searched" and "valued", "valued" compares to a single value using equality while "searched" can use any comparison operator. In you case you try to mix both.

Using "valued" is possible, but you need to specify each value on it's own:

```
CASE (CASE WHEN l.dnames = 'II-SH' THEN 'IW' 
     WHEN l.dnames = 'IIC-SH' THEN 'IW' 
     WHEN l.dnames = 'CD' THEN 'RPFX' 
     WHEN l.dnames LIKE '%-%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, '-',2,1)+1, 20 )
     WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EXCR%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames,  (INSTR(l.dnames, 'EXCR',1,1)+4),20)
     WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' AND l.ditems LIKE '%/%' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(l.ditems, 1,INSTR(l.ditems, '/',1)-1),'SINV')
     WHEN l.dnames = 'EX' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(l.ditems,'SINV'),'INV'), '[0-9]','')
     WHEN l.dnames LIKE 'EX%' THEN SUBSTR(l.dnames, INSTR(l.dnames, 'EX',1)+2 ,20)
     ELSE NULL 
     END)
WHEN 'BA' THEN 'First'
WHEN 'BG' THEN 'First'
WHEN 'BT' THEN 'First'
WHEN 'BW' THEN 'Second'
WHEN 'PF' THEN 'Second'
WHEN 'SS' THEN 'Second'
WHEN 'TC' THEN 'Third' 
WHEN 'NE' THEN 'Third'
ELSE NULL
END AS DGROUP
```